# Show that if $\lim f(x)=L$ then $\lim|f(x)|=|L|$. And, consequently if$ f(x)$ is continuous, then $|f(x)|$ is also continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Since $\lim f(x)=L$ then I know that I can use the straight definition of continuity with $|x-c|$, but I'm confused as to how the absolute value can be added in to be shown.

Comment: Use an extended triangle inequality: $| \ |a|-|b| \ | \leq |a - b|$

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Let $A\subset \mathbb R$, let $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and let $c\in \mathbb R$ be a cluster point of $A$. If $\lim_{x\to c}f$ exists, and if $|f|$ denotes the function defined for $x\in A$ by $|f|(x):=|f(x)|$, then

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists \delta\left(\varepsilon \right)>0,0<|x-c|<\delta\left(\varepsilon\right)\implies |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$$

But if $$w,z\in \mathbb R\implies ||w|-|z||\leq|w-z|$$
Then $f(x),L\in \mathbb R$
$$||f(x)|-|L||\leq |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$$
$$\therefore \lim_{x\to c}|f|=|L|=\left|\lim_{x\to c}f\right|$$
If $|L|=|f(c)|$ then $|f(x)|$ is continuous in point $c$.